# Conditions for a relation to be symmetric.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Let $A = \{1, 2, 3\}$, and $R$ be a relation on $A$.
$R = \{(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)\}$

Is **$R$** a symmetric relation? Since for all **$a R b$** there is **$b R a$**.
If **$R$** is not symmetric, then does that mean for a relation to be symmetric **$a$** must not equal to **$b$** ?

Comment: The definition says we must have $aRb$ iff $bRa$ $\forall a, b \in A$ which is true, so it is symmetric

Comment: It is symmetric. For instance, $\{(1,2)\}$ is not symmetric if you consider 1 and 2 as different symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$R$ is symmetric because $aRb \implies bRa$ for all $a,b \in A$.

As for your other query, no, nothing like that is needed. In fact, such a question desn't even arise if $a=b$.

Answer (score 0):

$R$ is a symmetric relation means if $(a,b)\in R$, then $(b,a)\in R$.
Elements of $R$ are $(1, {\color{red} 1}),(2, {\color{red} 2})$ and $(3,{\color{red} 3})$.

---

Now, you must check that   $({\color{red} 1},1 )$,$({\color{red} 2},2 )$ and $({\color{red} 3},3 )$ are elements of $R$.